# Threadsafe with ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I have an issue on which I need to run `.register` at most one time on a multi-threaded env, so i tried to use ConcurrentHashMap but seems like its not thread-safe or I'm using it correctly

```scala
object NonFunctionalMetrics {

  val histograms = new ConcurrentHashMap[String, Histogram](10).asScala
  def workerProcessingHistogram(name: String): Histogram = {
    val histogramName = s"${prefix}_${name.toSnakeCase}_processing_time"
    histograms.getOrElseUpdate(
                              key = histogramName,
                              op = Histogram.build(histogramName, s"${name} worker processing time in microseconds")
                                .labelNames("status")
                                .linearBuckets(config.service.metrics.http.histogramStart, config.service.metrics.http.histogramWidth, config.service.metrics.http.histogramCount)
                                .register()
    )
  }
}
```

throws me exception

```
Collector already registered that provides name: my_app_new_site_exclusion_worker_processing_time_count
```

on:

```
    val onSuccessHistogram: Histogram.Child = NonFunctionalMetrics.workerProcessingHistogram(worker.name).labelSuccess()
    val onFailureHistogram: Histogram.Child = NonFunctionalMetrics.workerProcessingHistogram(worker.name).labelFailure()
```

When I'm adding `synchronized` its working greats, as follows:

```scala
 def workerProcessingHistogram(name: String): Histogram = synchronized {
    val histogramName = s"${prefix}_${name.toSnakeCase}_processing_time"
    histograms.getOrElseUpdate(
                              key = histogramName,
                              op = Histogram.build(histogramName, s"${name} worker processing time in microseconds")
                                .labelNames("status")
                                .linearBuckets(config.service.metrics.http.histogramStart, config.service.metrics.http.histogramWidth, config.service.metrics.http.histogramCount)
                                .register()
    )
  }
```

I saw that the `get(key)` two threads are getting `false` answer and create the histogram with `register` - doesn't the ConcurrentHashMap need to handle those scenarios?

Comment: Well, this is just a shot into the blue: The access to your ConcurrentHashMap _is_ by definition thread safe, but your `workerProcessingHistogram` function is _not_. You first create the name and then access the histogram. So, it's not an atomic operation.

Comment: Haven't been on Java for some time now, but as far as I remeber, the `synchronized` keyword syncs on the class. So, _every_ call is "serialized" (not happening in parallel). UNfortunately, I am not up to date about possible alternatives, that will perform better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `computeIfAbsent` on the underlying Java ConcurrentHashMap. But `getOrElseUpdate` on a ConcurrentMap returned by `.asScala` will use the non-concurrent implementation of mutable Map in Scala.